# Translate CURL command to python code for fetching data from Cloudflare API

Tags: python, authentication, cloudflare

I tried to create python code for fetching api data of **CloudFlare analytics dashboard**. This is how I translated the following Curl command to Python:

I want to query out data for time duration 1 day(**from** 2018-11-18 00:00:00  **till** 2018-11-19 00:00:00).

**Curl command:**

```
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/cd7d0123e3012345da9420df9514dad0/analytics/dashboard?since=2018-11-18T00:00:00Z&until=2018-11-19T00:00:00Z&continuous=true" \
 -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 -H "X-Auth-Key:1234567893feefc5f0q5000bfo0c38d90bbeb" \
 -H "X-Auth-Email:example@example.com"
```

**Python Code:**

```
  import http.client, json

  def find_data():
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.cloudflare.com")
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'X-Auth-Email': "example@example.com",
        'X-Auth-Key': "1234567893feefc5f0q5000bfo0c38d90bbeb",
    }
    payload = "since=2018-11-18T00:00:00Z&until=2018-11-19T00:00:00Z&continuous=true"
    conn.request("POST", "/client/v4/zones/cd7d0123e3012345da9420df9514dad0/analytics/dashboard", payload, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read().decode('utf-8')
    loadedjson = json.loads(data)
    return(loadedjson)
  print(find_data())
```

**Problem:**

The script is working but i am getting data form 17 Nov till the current date i.e. i am not getting the queried data **from 18-19 Nov but 17-24**.

Is this the correct way to query the data from cloud flare, if not please correct it. If there is some other way in python to fetch data from API please modify the script.

Comment: In your translation you've changed the method from GET to POST. You've also named your query parameter variable *payload* which may be affecting your ability to search for the correct syntax. 

The reason you are seeing 1 week of data in the past is because that is the default for the api if it does not receive optional params in the form of a query string.

I don't know python so can't give you the code but you're close!

Comment: Reconsider switching to [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-Auth-Key': '1234567893feefc5f0q5000bfo0c38d90bbeb',
  'X-Auth-Email': 'example@example.com',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/cd7d0123e3012345da9420df9514dad0/analytics/dashboard?since=2018-11-18T00:00:00Z&until=2018-11-19T00:00:00Z&continuous=true', headers=headers)
```